# TFS: Undo checkout from "merge, branch, edit" to "merge, branch"

Tags: tfs

I have following situation:

- I have created some new projects in solution in one development branch in TFS
- I'm now merging them into the main branch.
- Architect has idea to merge two new modules into one.
- I have moved the code files
- Project files has already been changed within the merge.

These files have pending changes in form `merge, branch, edit`. I wan't to make this file `merge, branch, delete` but TFS won't do that because the file has pending changes. Is it possible to force the deletion or undo `edit` without undoing `merge, branch`?

I don't want to try the merge again and combine files from two shelvesets... Is there any possibility to modify the status of pending changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TFS does not support that.

You could "undo" the file and just pend a delete instead.

As best practice you shouldn't be making changes as part of a merge, you should just do the minimum possible to resolve the conflicts and get it to build (or not even that sometimes) and then make your required changes in a subsequent check-in. This makes it easier to see in the version control history what changes were made when - I very rarely look to see if a merge of a change is any different from a prior edit.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I expected the answer because I haven't found anything like that during googling. My only solution is to make the merge separately again and combine those two shelvesets...

The problem is, when you have conservative customers and you have to maintain versions in 20 year range and between branches are quite drastic differences and main branch is secured against invalid commits, thus you have to perform some changes during merge. Every product is not like java or flash forcing users to use only single latest unstable version and every other version is not working after next release.